# Current quantum theory of interference

Tags: quantum-mechanics, interference, superposition, wavefunction-collapse

I have always thought that the quantum theory states that interference occurs when photons behave like waves and two or more possible paths exist. Interference can then be destroyed if the path of the photons becomes known and consequently the photons behave like particles. Is this the current theory on interference? I am particularly wondering whether Feynman's work makes this model obsolete, or even flat out wrong.

Comment: Can you cite a book about quantum theory based on which you have acquired that belief?

Comment: here you go:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment

Comment: Yes, that's not a good place to learn quantum mechanics. It has too much irrelevant information and not enough of the necessary kind for the beginner.

Comment: So what is a good place? And what exactly did they get wrong? Honestly, I know that you particularly are opposed to wave-particle duality and you seem to have good sources but I find it odd that every paper, article, and book I have come across supports wave-particle duality.

Comment: A good place to start understanding Feynman's path integrals and quantum mechanics for beginners would be Feynman's own book "QED: The Strange Theory of Light and Matter". It's not perfect if you already know the final result, but it will get you more than halfway there to develop the necessary intuition but without the math. Feynman's paper "Space-Time Approach to Non-Relativistic Quantum Mechanics" R. P. Feynman Rev. Mod. Phys. 20, 367 works it out on the professional level.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a number of reasons why wave-particle duality is not a good idea. One of the more obvious ones is actually a lesson in classical physics. It starts with what we mean when we are talking about particles. These are the very first few sentences in the first chapter of the book "Mechanics" by Landau-Lifshitz:

"One of the fundamental concepts of mechanics is that of the particle. By this we mean a body whose dimensions can be neglected in describing its motion. The possibility of doing so depends, of course, on the conditions of the problem concerned. For example, the planets may be regarded as particles in considering their motion about the Sun, but not in considering their rotation about their axes."

As you can see, these authors clearly state that "particle" is not a property of a physical body but a physicist's choice of a suitable description of its dynamics.  Sometimes it fits for even very large bodies and sometimes it doesn't. One could make a similar argument about waves. If you try to apply this to quantum phenomena, then you have to ask yourself what your criteria would be to call a quantum object a particle? Is an atom a particle? How about a ten ton superconducting magnet? Which of these two would you call "a wave"?

The second argument comes from logic and it simply states that wave-particle duality is a false application of the rule of excluded third (or middle). Just because we know about particles and waves in classical mechanics and because some quantum phenomena seem to behave like one at one time and another under different circumstances doesn't mean there can't be a third category that is neither particle nor wave. To postulate that is simply extremely shoddy logical thinking that somehow has made it into this artificial synthesis of wave-particle-duality.

Good logic doesn't follow the synthesis pattern but it treats individual phenomena individually. Instead of pounding square pegs into round holes we can simply admit that "OK, if quantum objects don't really behave like either, how about we call them "quantum objects" and let them form a third and completely new category?"

If it doesn't walk like a duck and it doesn't quack like a duck, it's not a duck.

Simple, isn't it? Now that you have freed your mind from unnecessary ballast, you can try quantum mechanics fresh and without the need for an extra large mallet.

Comment: Thank you very much. That makes perfect sense. I feel like in general, quantum physicists make things much harder than they actually are.

Comment: This one is hard in the sense that one simply has to accept that the classical world is a by-product of the quantum world, not the other way around. Quantum effects are not some fickle stuff that only happens in the physics lab. That matter exists in the first place is a pure quantum effect. No classical theory can predict stable matter. Pick up any piece of matter and you are holding a macroscopic quantum effect in your hand. Same for any permanent magnet. Light, chemistry, plants photosynthesizing, you name it. If you can let go of old concepts you will have much more fun with all of this.

Comment: @CuriousOne. Can you add this answer to every single question on physics.se about wave particle duality? Thanks in advance :) +1

Comment: @march: Will do my best. :-)